# Two different GPS locations given from same code

Tags: iphone, xcode, gps, cllocation

So I'm very very very very new to programming, but I've fumbled my way through this far: I'm creating an Iphone App, 
My goal is to create an automatic stopwatch; something that starts itself at a pre-set location and stops itself at a pre-set location ( both of which are set by the user). If the pre-set gps location and the actual gps location are equal, a timer will start/stop.  I've done this by setting a location as a variable at the push of a button.

here's the problem: The two values are never equal. The pre-set start and finish locations contain many more decimals than the "actual" location ( the values themselves, not just the printed values) and if they are never equal, the timer will not start.

any help is appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply calculate the distance between the two coordinates and start/stop the timer when the distance drops below a certain threshold (e.g. 50m) to the start or end location.

`CLLocation` provides a convient method for doing so:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

For example:

```
 double lat = 51.7;
 double lng = 7.0;
 CLLocation *locationStart = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lng];
 CLLocation *currentLocation = ...; // received from location services

 if ([locationStart distanceFromLocation:currentLocation] < 50) {
     // start timer 
 }
```

You may also consider using the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the current location instead of the arbitrary 50m. Beware however that the accuracy can be as bad as several kilometers. Something like `MIN(horizontalAccuracy, 50)` may work well.

Comment: :what data type is usable with CLLocation? I've tried setting it equal to an integer, a float, and a double and it keeps rejecting the variable and saying it's the wrong format.

Comment: CLLocation is an object-class. To create an instance you need the latitude and longitude ideally as doubles (or CLLocationDegrees which is double). You can then create it with `[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lng]`